# Media Plugin Error Code: 1

Tags: javascript, android, audio, cordova

I haven't been able to get a local sound playing using the Cordova Media plugin.

I have the right options in my `platforms\android\res\xml\config.xml` here...

```
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
<preference name="loglevel" value="DEBUG" />
<feature name="App">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.App" />
</feature>
<feature name="Device">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.device.Device" />
</feature>
<feature name="File">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.file.FileUtils" />
</feature>
<feature name="Media">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.media.AudioHandler" />
</feature>
<feature name="SplashScreen">
    <param name="android-package" value="org.apache.cordova.splashscreen.SplashScreen" />
</feature>
```

...and the permission option in my `AndroidManifest.xml`...

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" android:targetSdkVersion="19" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
```

However when I try to play a sound I get nothing:

[image]

*Note: I'm using Apache Cordova 3.3.0*

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Managed to figure it out in the end you have to reference the file paths relative to the `window.location.pathname` as when run through Apache Cordova the root is `file:///android_asset/www/` so the sounds must be referenced like so `/android_asset/www/path/to/a/sound.mp3`.

Here's my full solution:

```
var audio = {
    root: '',
    localPath: '/assets/sounds/',
    manifest: {
        bang: 'bang.mp3',
        boom: 'boom.mp3',
        splat: 'splat.mp3',
        splash: 'splash.mp3'
    },
    sounds: {},
    parse: function () {
        var p = window.location.pathname;
        this.root = p.substring(0, p.lastIndexOf('/')) + this.localPath;
        console.log(this.root);
        for (var sound in this.manifest) {
            var src = this.root + this.manifest[sound];
            console.log('Getting sound: ' + src);
            this.sounds[sound] = (typeof Media !== 'undefined') ? new Media(src) : new Audio(src);
            console.log('Created sound:');
        $('#sounds').append($('<li></li>').html(src));
        }
    }
};
audio.parse();
```

So for instance my `index.html` is in my root which is essentially `./` from my perspective (the `www` folder).

All my sounds are within two sub folders `./assets/sounds/`.

When hosting the application on my PC `window.location.pathname` appears as `/`:

[image]

However when hosted on my mobile device it is:

[image]

Comment: I have the same error with a local file. You said "android_asset/www/" and after "/assets/sounds/", i don't understand... what is the path to put ? my files are in "nameOfApp/www/data/" before the build

Comment: Updated with more explanation let me know if it makes sense now.

Comment: Say I use the Audio API. How do I tell if the audio is finished playing?

Answer (score 5):

After doing a bit of digging as to how the Media plugin goes about playing audio naively via Android's [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer.html), I see that for some unknown reason the following permissions are required in the `\platforms\androidAndroidManifest.xml`.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

***Internet Permission** - If you are using MediaPlayer to stream network-based content, your application must request network access.*

I can only guess that because you're trying to stream local media via a WebView it requires this permission to function correctly.

However it would have been nice to get a better error message than `undefined` maybe something like.

```
code: 1
message: Missing Android permission
```

*Apache Cordova should have added this permission automatically when installing the plugin.*

**EDIT: Actually this is only a partial fix for accessing remote audio files I still have yet to get local files working.**

Comment: I do not have WAKE_LOCK and the internet one (as well as all others) where created by the plugin (I did not edit the manifest manually).  Like I said in my answer it does work on Android with local files so im not sure this would help.

Comment: Yes this makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 3):

Here is my code and it works. make sure to install the [device plugin](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-device)

```
if(selectedSoundOption === "Coins"){
        var coin180Url = getMediaURL("sounds/coin180.mp3");
        var coin180 = new Media(coin180Url, null, mediaError);
        var coin360Url = getMediaURL("sounds/coin360.wav");
        var coin360 = new Media(coin360Url, null, mediaError);
        if(rotation.indexOf("360") > -1){
            coin180.play();
        }else{
            coin360.play();
        }
    }
}

function mediaError(e) {
    alert('Media error '+e);
}

function getMediaURL(s) {
    if(device.platform.toLowerCase() === "android") return "/android_asset/www/" + s;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: This is kind of a hardcoded platform solution. You can actually obtain the exact root using my solution below regardless of platform.

Comment: I find this solution more straightforward. It is hardcoded for android because this is an android-specific quirk (bug?). In ios/browser it works with no prefix.

Answer (score 0):

After adding following lines in android \platforms\androidAndroidManifest.xml, sounds is played.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

Thanks Joshua, you solution works out for me.